# Error 404 on Flask app

Tags: python, flask

I'm starting off with flask, I have this code on my `app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES

app = Flask(__name__)

photos = UploadSet('photos', IMAGES)

app.config['UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST'] = 'static/img'
configure_uploads(app, photos)

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'photo' in request.files:
        filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
        return filename
    return render_template('upload.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My `upload.html` code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=POST enctype=multipart/form-data action="{{ url_for('upload') }}">
    <input type=file name=photo>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the file hyerarchy:

```
├── image_upload
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.py
│   │   ├── app.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── routes.py
│   │   ├── routes.pyc
│   │   └── upload.html
│   ├── image_upload.py
│   ├── image_upload.pyc
│   └── static
│       ├── img
│       └── templates
│           └── upload.html
└── install.sh
```

My `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

My `routes.py` although I'm not using it:

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/upload')
def index():
    return upload
```

And the `image_upload.py` file:

```
from app import app
```

It always throws Error 404 when I browse it, could it be the `routes.py` file?

I'm a fresher on `flask` so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also if I import the routes file from **init** it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/bin/flask", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 513, in main
cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 380, in main
return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 423, in run_command
app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 152, in __init__
self._load_unlocked()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 176, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 237, in load_app
rv = locate_app(self.app_import_path)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/paper_flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 90, in locate_app
__import__(module)
File "/home/kristian/paper/remote_sensing_1/image_upload/image_upload.py", line 1, in <module>
from app import app
File "/home/kristian/paper/remote_sensing_1/image_upload/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from app import routes
ImportError: cannot import name routes
```

Comment: Your PYTHONPATH is the `app` folder for the import to work is has to be the `image_upload` folder. Start your app from there with `python app/app.py`.

Comment: If you're not using `routes.py` why do you import it in line 5 of `__init__.py`?

Comment: @KlausD. that was it, thank You very much